# FlutterFire error: "The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed"

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-tools

iam new to flutterfire whenever i try to type the command "flutterfire configure" in the terminal of my project directory i get an error

the error is

> Found 0 Firebase projects.
> FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
> COMMAND: firebase --version
> ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.

i just installed firebase Cli from the official website so it's updated

i have no node.js experience so i installed from the option standalone binary as recommanded
i already created my firebase project from the website but it dosen't read it on the terminal saying "0 Firebase projects" as i showed above

Comment: Please edit the question to explain exactly what you've done so far to get to this error message.  We should be able to follow your instructions and duplicate the results.  In particular, we don't know how you installed the Firebase CLI, or that you've correctly added it to your path.